# How to prove $\ln x - \ln a < (x - a)/\sqrt{ ax }$ ($x > a >0$) by Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inequality

I have already proved this,

Let $φ(x) = \ln x$,

$\dfrac {\ln x - \ln a }{x-a}$ = $φ'(ξ)$ = $\frac1{ξ} = \frac 1 {\sqrt {ξ^2}} < \frac 1 {\sqrt {ξa}}$ ($x > ξ >a$)

I know how to prove it by setting up a function

$g(x) = \ln x - \ln a - \frac {x-a} {\sqrt {ax}}$

All I need is a proof by Mean Value Theorem. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes, without Mean Value Theorem it's very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\ln(x)$ and $g(x)=\ln(x)$.

By the mean value theorem we have
$$\forall u>1, \frac{g(u)-g(1)}{u-1}=\frac{\ln u}{u-1}=\frac{1}{v}\le 1$$
Because $1<v<u$.
this can be rearranged as follows
$$\forall u>1, \frac{\ln u+1}{u}\le 1$$
Now, again
By the mean value theorem, for all $t>1$ there exists $s$ with $1<s<t$ such that
$$ \frac{f(t)-f(1)}{t-1}=\frac{\sqrt{t}\ln t}{t-1}
=\frac{\ln s}{2\sqrt{s}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}=
\frac{\ln\sqrt{s}+1}{\sqrt{s}}\le 1$$
Now, appy the obtained inequality with $t=x/a$.

**Edit:** I want to share with you my first thought about this question. It was to give a simple proof regardless of the mean value theorem, well it was using the arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality, it goes as follows:
$$\eqalign{\frac{\ln x-\ln a}{x-a}&=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{a+t(x-a)}=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1-t)a+tx}\cr
&\le\int_0^1\frac{dt}{a^{1-t}x^t}=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^1e^{t\ln(a/x)}\,dt\cr
&=\frac1a\cdot\frac{e^{\ln(a/x)}-1}{\ln(a/x)}=\frac{1}{ax}\cdot\frac{a-x}{\ln a-\ln x}
}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{\ln x-\ln a}{x-a}\right)^2\le \frac{1}{ax}.$$
Isn't this beautiful!?.

Comment: Felix, you answer is so neat and tricky.  If you are not intuitive to get the answer, can you give me a reference that you read about using Mean Value Theorem to think and solve the question like this? I want to know how you find the auxiliary function if it's not  instinctive.

Comment: @M.Chen, in fact this was not my first thought, I tried several possibilities, this was the first to give what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apply MVT to $2\ln(t/a)-(t/a)+(a/t)$ on $[a,x]$ and use the fact that $(y-a)(x-y)>0$ if $y$ is between $a$ and $x$.

Comment: Kavi, I don't want you to spoon me the answer,  but I cannot work out by the   method you provided. All I got is $2 \frac {ln x - ln a} {x - a} - \frac {x + a} {ax} = -a (\frac 1{ξ} - \frac 1{a})^2 > -a  (\frac 1{x} - \frac 1{a})^2$. And this doesn't leat to the result. Can you give me a hint or some detail? Thank you