# How to prove $ ln x/x > 2/e^2 (e<x<e^2) $ by Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inequality

I already asked a similar question here,

[How to prove $\ln x - \ln a < (x - a)/\sqrt{ ax }$ ($x > a >0$) by Mean Value Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373045/how-to-prove-ln-x-ln-a-x-a-sqrt-ax-x-a-0-by-mean-value-th)

and Felix Clein had provided me two beautiful methods. I tried, but those methods cannot be adapted to this question.

I know the other simple method by just finding the derivative of $ ln x / x $ and I also know the MVT is not panacea. I just want to master the skills to find the auxiliary function and more tricks to prove inequality.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(s)=\frac{\log s}{s},\ s\in[e,e^2],$ for any $x\in(e,e^2)$

$$F(e^2)-F(x)=\frac{\log e^2}{e^2}-\frac{\log x}{x}=(e^2-x)\frac{1-\log \xi}{\xi^2}<0 .$$
here $\xi$ is some number between $e$ and $e^2$.